# How do I stream a file stored in GCP Cloud Storage through a NestJS 13 route handler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, next.js13

I have a pretty standard problem - I want my NextJS app to serve images stored in GCP Cloud Storage, but I want to keep those images protected and only available to authorized users of my web app, so the bucket those images are stored in is private.

I'm aware of two ways to solve this:

#### 1. Use signed urls.

I can use [GCP's Javascript SDK](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) to easily create signed URLs for each image I want to serve.  Once you get the GCP credentials squared away this is pretty easy, but the signing itself is actually pretty computationally expensive. I'm running this app in Cloud Run on a 1vCPU instance and it was taking between 100ms to 200ms just for the signing.

On top of that, the signed URLs really impact your caching options.  Not ideal.

#### 2. Create your own API endpoint that streams the image from GCP

With this option we can simply pass the image through from GCP direction to the HTTP requestor. As long as the latency between Cloud Run and Cloud Storage is low, as assuming the streaming process doesn't tax the CPU too much, this gives me all my caching options back and is my preferred option.

NextJS 13's documentation is generally quite good, but I found the [streaming section](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#streaming) a bit light for my needs.  I'm looking for a concrete example on how to do this in my app.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging and experimenting, I came up with this and it's done the job nicely.

```js
// File location: app/api/image/[id]/route.ts

import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: '$PROJECT_ID',
});

interface GCPFileStream {
  size: number;
  name: string;
  contentType: string;
  stream: ReadableStream;
}

interface RequestParams {
  params: {
    id: string;
  };
}

// Our HTTP handler
export async function GET(request: Request, { params }: RequestParams): Promise<Response> {
  // NOTE: Don't forget to check auth, either in the handler or some middleware

  const fileStream = await readFile(Number(params.id));

  return new NextResponse(fileStream.stream, {
    status: 200,
    headers: new Headers({
      'Cache-Control': 'max-age=2592000, stale-while-revalidate=86400, private',
      'Content-Type': fileStream.contentType,
      'Content-Length': fileStream.size.toString(),
    }),
  });
}

// The helper function to read the file from GCP
async function readFile(imageId: number): Promise<GCPFileStream> {
  const bucketName = '$BUCKET_NAME';
  const fileName = `${imageId}.jpg`;

  // fetch file size, content type, etc
  const fileMetadata = await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).getMetadata();
  const stats = fileMetadata[0];

  const readStream = storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).createReadStream();

  return {
    size: Number(stats.size) || 0,
    name: stats.name || '',
    contentType: stats.contentType || '',
    stream: readStream as unknown as ReadableStream,
  };
}
```

Improvement suggestions are always welcome!